# SxS error in Windows 7 when trying to run a Matlab-Compiler-Runtime application

Tags: windows, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler, side-by-side

I'm trying to run a data analysis tool that was built as a standalone Matlab application on a Windows 7 machine.  I've installed the Matlab Compiler Runtime (MCR) libraries version 7.11, 2009b.  When I attempt to launch the application ELISAgui.exe I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\amatteson\temp\ELISAgui>ELISAgui.exe
My Own Exception: Fatal error loading library C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\MATL
AB Compiler Runtime\v711\bin\win32\mclmcr.dll Error: The application has failed
to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the app
lication event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
```

I first attempted a reboot.  Then a repair install of the MCR environment.  Then a delete and totally new install.  No change in the error.  So I decided to brave my inexperience with Windows (I'm very much a Linux or Mac guy) and break out the sxstrace tool.  I followed the procedure outlined here ["Diagnosing side by side failures"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/04/14/576314.aspx) and arrived with the following output from the tool (my sincere apologies for posting the full trace, but I'm not sure what's relevant):

```
=================
Begin Activation Context Generation.
Input Parameter:
    Flags = 0
    ProcessorArchitecture = Wow32
    CultureFallBacks = en-US;en
    ManifestPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v711\bin\win32\hg.dll
    AssemblyDirectory = C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v711\bin\win32\
    Application Config File = 
-----------------
INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v711\bin\win32\hg.dll.
    INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is (null).
    INFO: Reference: Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762"
    INFO: Reference: Microsoft.VC80.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762"
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT\8.0.50727.762__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: Find publisher policy at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_policy.8.0.microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4927_none_516ad11f0f4bdafe.manifest
                INFO: Publisher Policy redirected assembly version.
                INFO: Post policy assembly identity is Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.4927".
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4927_none_d08a205e442db5b5.manifest.
                INFO: Manifest found at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4927_none_d08a205e442db5b5.manifest.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.4927".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui\8.0.50727.4927_en-US_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui\8.0.50727.4927_en_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui\8.0.50727.4927_en-US_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui\8.0.50727.4927_en_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC80.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.MFC\8.0.50727.762__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.MFC.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.MFC\8.0.50727.762__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.MFC.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v711\bin\win32\Microsoft.VC80.MFC.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v711\bin\win32\Microsoft.VC80.MFC.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v711\bin\win32\Microsoft.VC80.MFC\Microsoft.VC80.MFC.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v711\bin\win32\Microsoft.VC80.MFC\Microsoft.VC80.MFC.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    ERROR: Cannot resolve reference Microsoft.VC80.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762".
ERROR: Activation Context generation failed.
End Activation Context Generation.
```

Again, my sincere apologies for posting the full log, but it's Greek to me. I'm not sure how to proceed and would appreciate some pointers.

Comment: Helped me debug my issue even though Notepad was refusing to properly decode "Unicode". At least "VC8.0" was there. Let's not talk about interop when MS apps can't even make sense of their own encodings, yeah...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like you're runnning a 32-bit compiled Matlab app on a 64-bit Windows machine, and it's not finding the 32-bit Visual C++ runtime it's linked against. (On 64-bit Windows, 32-bit applications run in a 32-bit subsystem and are linked against 32-bit versions of their libraries.) IIRC, the MCR installer for earlier versions may not install all of its Visual C++ Runtime dependencies. You may need to install it yourself.

I think "VC80" corresponds to Visual Studio 2005. Check your Add and Remove Programs control panel to see which "Microsoft Visual C++ XXXX Redistributable" ones are installed. (On the x64 XP box I use for Matlab development, I have nearly a dozen variants.) You'll need the 32-bit (x86) 2005 one, which is named "Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable". It does *not* have " (x64)" at the end of it's name; that's the 64-bit one. They can both be installed simultaneously on a 64-bit system.

If you don't have it installed, download it from here, install it, and try running the app again. If that doesn't work, try installing the 2008 version too.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5638